# What happen if I don't commit() or rollback() an unmanaged sequelize transaction?

Tags: javascript, node.js, transactions, sequelize.js

My team just got a project and it's a handover project (that developed by other previous vendor/software house). We're asked by the project owner to maintain the legacy codes and fix bugs (if any).

The project is using Node.js/Express, Sequelize (ORM), PostgreSQL. And then, when I was trying to understand the legacy codes here and there, I found an unmanaged [sequelize transaction](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions/) with pattern like below:

```js
const createUser = async (req, res) => {
  const t = await db.transaction();
  try {
    const { phone, email, password } = req.body;
    
    const existedUser = await User.findOne({
      where: {
        [Op.or]: {
          phone: phone,
          email: email.toLowerCase(),
        },
        deleted_at: null,
      },
    });
    
    if (!existedUser){
      const newUser = await User.create(
        {
          phone: phone,
          email: email.toLowerCase(),
          password: hash(password),
        },
        { transaction: t }
      );
      
      await t.commit();
      res.status(200).json({
        isSuccess: true,
        statusCode: 200,
        responseMessage: "User created successfully",
        data: newUser,
      });
    } else {
      // The problem I'm wondering about is here
      // No transaction commit or rollback in this case
      res.status(400).json({
        isSuccess: false,
        statusCode: 400,
        responseMessage: "User already exist",
        data: null,
      });
    }
    
  } catch (err) {
    await t.rollback();
    res.status(500).json({
      isSuccess: false,
      statusCode: 500,
      responseMessage: err.message,
      data: null,
    });
  }
}
```

1. Is it ok to have a case where an unmanaged transaction not be done manually (without committing or rolling back)?
2. What happen if we have many cases like above in our application? What are the consequences?
3. Will undone transactions like above waste our resources? Will these undone transactions slow our web backend app?

Comment: If you close the database connection without committing, it should automatically rollback.

Comment: So it's okay to have an undone sequelize transaction case? Will my node.js backend app running with good performance?

Comment: I'm not familar with sequelize, but it seems unlikely that it would change how the underlying database operations work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Transactions should be as short as possible and, of course, you should close them (by commit or rollback) regardless how many paths in code you have. To avoid such scenarios I recommend you to use managed transactions - that way you'll have a guarantee that a transaction will be committed or rolled back (unless you have an endless callback).
2. If an idle time of an uncommitted transaction is large enough in DB settings than you could end up with many uncommitted changes that could block future transactions if they intersect in the same records
3. Uncommitted transactions definitely spend DB resources (including growing transaction log). They could slow DB performance and hold some amount of backend memory occupied.

All in all you shouldn't have such cases with uncommitted transactions at all. This also could lead to unpredictable results if the app assumes the changes already committed while they are not.